# how to delete installation class data via api or php function in back4app

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform, push-notification, back4app

I have back4app backend in my flutter app, we have total 12k+ user in app and in installation class has 12k+ data and when I send a notification at the notification don't reach to all user.

after discussing with back4app team I found that many user has uninstall app that why those device token is expire and you have to delete expire tokon from the installation class,

but in back4app has not any function or code that help to delete unregister device token or even its provide access installation class full access to deleted specific data using PHP function

Please help me if you have knowledge about back4app and you know about the installation class issue.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What do you think of creating a cloud code function to delete them?
Make sure you'll use the master key and also test it on a different app, to avoid affecting your production app.

As cloud code uses the Javascript SDK, you can use the following guide as a reference:
https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#destroying-objects

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that way;

1-) Please delete all sessions.

2-) while sending notification, you should query on session class and which user open the currently your app, you matched their users and send notification this users